# Document overwrite prevention and notification

Tags: document, popup, notifications

Can you ‘turn-off’ the overwrite function in CRM so no documents can ever be overwritten? If a document with the same name is being uploaded, can the system prompt the user that they cannot save a document with the same name?

It would be helpful if you can mention the steps if the above is possible?

It is sharepoint server.

Comment: Is it SharePoint Server or SharePoint online ?